# How to set text dfm value to checked on all dfm files/Count number of lines in .dfm binary file

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

with below example i am counting number of lines in .dfm file and the count is coming wrong because .dfm is saved in binary format.

if i open .dfm file and do right click and set text dfm to checked and the count is coming correctly. Below is the code

```
function TForm1.FindNumberOfLinesInFile(FileName: String): Integer;
var
  contents : TStringList;
  filestream : TFileStream;
  outStream : TMemoryStream;
begin
  try
    try
      Result := 0;
      contents := TStringList.Create;
      if edtFileToSearch.Text = '.dfm' then
      begin
        contents.LoadFromFile(FileName);
        //i am binary
        if pos('OBJECT', Uppercase(contents[0])) = 0 then // Count is coming wrong with this
        begin
          contents.Clear;
          fileStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmShareDenyNone);
          outStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
          try
            ObjectResourceToText(filestream,outStream);
            outStream.Position := 0;
            Contents.LoadFromStream(outStream);
          finally
            FreeAndNil(outStream);
          end;
        end
        else
        begin
          fileStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmShareDenyNone);
          Contents.LoadFromStream(fileStream);
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
          fileStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmShareDenyNone);
          Contents.LoadFromStream(filestream);
      end;
      Result := contents.Count;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(fileStream);
      FreeAndNil(contents);
    end;
  except
    on e: Exception do Result := -1;
  end;
end;
```

i have 2 questions

1)how to set text dfm value to checked in all dfm files(i have around 1000 dfm files)?

2)how load binary file correctly and count number of lines?

Comment: in Delphi 7 under the `Tools -> Environment Options -> Designer` there is a checkbox `New forms as text` - check it so that by default new forms will be in text format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi comes with a command line tool to do this, named `convert`. Open up a command prompt and ensure that your Delphi bin directory is in the `PATH`. Then type:

```
C:\projects\myprocject> convert
```

The output will be something like this:

```
Delphi Form Conversion Utility Version 5.0
Copyright (c) 1995,99 Inprise Corporation
Usage: convert.exe [-i] [-s] [-t | -b] 
  -i  Convert files in-place (output overwrites input)
  -s  Recurse subdirectories
  -t  Convert to text
  -b  Convert to binary
```

So, you should be able to write:

```
C:\projects\myprocject> convert -i -s -t *.dfm
```

to effect the change required.

Comment: Note that since SO posts are meant to contain a single question, I am choosing to answer just one of your two questions.

Answer (score 0):

David's answer addresses the first of your questions:  You can convert all of your existing binary DFM's to text using the command line tool provided with Delphi.

As well as addressing your immediate problem this is also highly recommended as it will make it much easier (i.e. possible at all!) to visually diff changes to your DFM files in version control.

As for the second part, if for some reason you still want or need to handle binary DFM files in your code is to use the **TestStreamFormat()** function to determine whether a stream is a valid resource stream and whether it is binary or text format, before calling **ObjectResourceToText()** function only if required.

This helper function to return the contents of a specified filename (of a DFM) into a supplied **TStrings** (e.g. a **TStringlist**) demonstrates this and might simplify things for you:

```
procedure GetDfmIntoStrings(aFilename: String; aStrings: TStrings);
var
  istrm, ostrm: TStream;
begin
  ostrm := NIL;
  istrm := TFileStream.Create(aFilename, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
  try
    case TestStreamFormat(istrm) of

      sofBinary : begin
                    ostrm := TStringStream.Create('');
                    ObjectResourceToText(istrm, ostrm)
                  end;

      sofText   : ostrm := istrm;

    else
      raise EFilerError.Create(aFilename + ' is not a valid resource stream (DFM)');
    end;

    ostrm.Position := 0;
    aStrings.LoadFromStream(ostrm);

  finally
    if ostrm <> istrm then
      ostrm.Free;

    istrm.Free;
  end;
end;
```